# If I have an S3 lifecycle rule to pemanently delete expired versions, will it apply also when the current version is a delete marker?

Tags: amazon-s3

If I have a versioned bucket with a file, and the next day I delete that file, I am left with:

- Delete marker for somefile.jpg (timestamp now)

  - somefile.jpg (timestamp yesterday)

I want a lifecycle rule that will permanently delete noncurrent versions after a while, and **if the only current version is a delete marker, then the whole thing should be gone**.

1. Will the following rule achieve that?
2. Will the following rule also retroactively apply to versions deleted more than 180 days ago, even if I'm creating the rule today?

[image: Lifecycle rule 1]
[image: Lifecycle rule 2]
[image: Lifecycle rule 3]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the following rule achieve that?

Yes, it will delete the expired delete marker and permanently delete the previous versions of the object if the previous versions are more than 180 days old.

> Will the following rule also retroactively apply to versions deleted more than 180 days ago, even if I'm creating the rule today?

Yes, it is retroactive. You can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547572/amazon-s3-lifecycle-retroactive-application).