# Does a new lifecycle management rule for aws s3 also applies to objects which are already older than threshold days provided in rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-lifecycle-policy

Example 1:
Let us assume I have 2 objects in my s3 bucket.

**obj1** : **size=** 5 gb ;     **age** = 35 days old ; **current class** = S3 std

**Obj2** : **size** = 5 gb ;  **age**= 29 days old  ; **current class** = s3 std

now if I create a rule to transition to S3 Infrequent Access class  ( applied to whole bucket)  after 30 days.

Which of the above two objects will be transitioned and when?

Comment: Obj1 would be moved to IA right away and Obj2 would be moved tomorrow

Comment: @palvarez yes but keep in mind S3 lifecycle rules don't really occur "right away", they can take several hours in my experience to actually happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon S3 lifecycle retroactive application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547572/amazon-s3-lifecycle-retroactive-application)

Comment: @MarkB that is true, let's say the object is flagged right away and moved when the queue gets to it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.